# View upload files in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am trying to view text file how i uploaded in dataGridView 
i can upload the files from folder how i chose put i have this erroe when the dataGridView should view it :access to path denied

this is my code

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //
                // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
                // We print the number of files found.
                //
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
                 string file = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                string[] textData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.ToString());
                //textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.ToString();
                string[] headers = textData[0].Split(',');

            DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
            foreach (string header in headers)
                dataTable1.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string), null);

            for (int i = 1; i < textData.Length; i++)
                dataTable1.Rows.Add(textData[i].Split(','));

            //Set the DataSource of DataGridView to the DataTable
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;

        }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the Error?

Comment: i used the array string to get all files and it is work when i trying to get files in file string they dont pass and give that error       the error in this line  string file = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);